# How does Apple build this animated first login screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

When a new user is created, we see this animated window:

[image: Animated Window]
<sub>(source: [idanfe.com](http://www.idanfe.com/images/sample.png))</sub>

I am interested in building a similar window in the new version of my app, which migrates old data into new data.

Which objects is Apple using to animate the window?

Comment: Which of the animation methods provided by Cocoa have you considered and rejected as unsuitable, and why?

Comment: I think Apple might be using Quartz to draw the window, or simply has an NSimageView that changes its content using a set of images. The first possibility looks a bit "too much" work to achieve, and the last one seems a little bit amateur for a programmer. I really did not reject any methods, but I was seeking advice from people who have done it before. Would you be so kind to mention just 2 methods that 'animate'? I mean: not start a bezier and draw an object, but a cocoa method capable of true animation? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that this is not a place for learning, but a place for competition on who gets most "good points". Some people might feel discouraged to ask, and end up ashamed as I feel now. I have posted a very reasonable question here, which was voted 3 times negative, put on hold for being a "opinion based" question, although I have read it more than 30 times, I still don't see it so. My answer was deleted. This looks a very hostile environment for me. I am sorry to tell you. It is how I feel. I am not certain if stack overflow has a real future as a learning tool. Good bye.

Answer (score 1):

It could be multiple images moving with respect to time, giving you a feel of animation.

You can also try your hands on `NSBezierPath` to draw yourself, but mind it - Its wouldn't be so easy to achieve this.